# How to get a data structure having the features both circular buffer in the boost and unordered_map in the STL?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, boost, data-structures

A series of data need to be added to my program. That data can be processed many times,so there is a counting number association with each data. If the counting number is greater that a fixed value, my program will do something.

I guess this data structure should have o(1) complexity, since I need to search the counting number. And I want to make the data structure bounded in case of the out of memory, since the number of data is unknown. It is fine that the new value overwrite the old value.

My question is if there has been an existed library that has such similar data structure?  If the answer is no, my concern is what is the best way to achievement it? How to make it thread safe?

I know that there has been an circular buffer in the boost and unordered_map in STL. It seems like the data structure I want is the combination  of them.

For example:

```
std::unordered_map<string,int> values;  ///key: a string, value : a counter
    std::string key{"a"};
    if(values.find(key) != values.end())
    {
        values.emplace({key,1});
    }else{
        auto count = values[key];
        if(count > 20){
            do_something();
        } else {
            ++values[key];
        }
    }
```

Add comments:

What I concerned is to do something when the counter is greater a fixed value. But I don't how many values need to be processed, I want to keep the data structure in fixed memory and it is better that the new value overwrites the old value.

Comment: You'll need to more clearly delineate what exact operations you need, and how exactly previous data should be dropped when you exceed your limit.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your quick response. I add some comments, I appreciate you give me some help. Many thanks.

Comment: And which values would you like to be overwritten first when adding new ones? The 'oldest' in the map, or just any value, e.g. the one that happens to be at map.begin()?

Comment: According to the policy which the value should be overwritten, there are some policies, FIFO, LRU, LFU, MRU.

Comment: According to the policy which the value should be overwritten, there are some policies, FIFO, LRU, LFU, MRU. In my situation, if the counter is greater than the fixed value, it should be definitely overwritten. But if the counter is less than the fixed value,  the counter which is **furthest** to the fixed value and isn't the recently used should be overwritten. Do you have any idea?

Comment: One more question: why have you suggested to use int as value? You said you want to search by counter - this implies that the counter should be the key.

Comment: The counter is to count the number of a string. That is the result that I want to get from the cache. So the the string will be the key and the counter will be value .I decided to use the LRU finally.